# Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: nginx, centos7

I follow the steps to [setup a nginx server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-on-centos-7). After I create **example.com.config** and symbolic link for each server block in the **sites-enabled** directory. My nginx can't start.

I can't restart nginx service. It shows the following message when I entered

**$sudo systemctl restart nginx.service**

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**$sudo systemctl status nginx.service -l** shows the following message.

```
● nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-06-05 04:26:05 EDT; 1min 27s ago
     Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
  Process: 4776 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 11491 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 05 04:26:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
Jun 05 04:26:05 localhost.localdomain nginx[11491]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
Jun 05 04:26:05 localhost.localdomain nginx[11491]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
Jun 05 04:26:05 localhost.localdomain nginx[11491]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jun 05 04:26:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 05 04:26:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
Jun 05 04:26:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Jun 05 04:26:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
```

PS: I am running under CentOS 7 on virtualbox.
Please help me. Thank you.

Here's the output when I run `ls -lart /var/run/`

```
total 56
dr-xr-xr-x. 17 root           root            233 Jun  2 05:37 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             60 Jun  6 01:21 tmpfiles.d
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root           root             60 Jun  6 01:21 log
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             60 Jun  6 01:21 mount
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root           root            120 Jun  6 01:21 initramfs
prw-------.  1 root           root              0 Jun  6 01:21 dmeventd-server
prw-------.  1 root           root              0 Jun  6 01:21 dmeventd-client
drwx------.  2 root           root             80 Jun  6 01:21 lvm
-rw-r--r--.  1 root           root              4 Jun  6 01:21 lvmetad.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             60 Jun  6 01:21 sysconfig
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jun  6 01:21 samba
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jun  6 01:21 setrans
drwxrwxr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jun  6 01:21 netreport
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jun  6 01:21 faillock
drwx------.  2 rpc            rpc              40 Jun  6 01:21 rpcbind
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jun  6 01:21 ppp
drwxrwxr-x.  3 root           libstoragemgmt   60 Jun  6 01:21 lsm
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jun  6 01:21 spice-vdagentd
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jun  6 01:21 sepermit
drwxr-xr-x.  2 radvd          radvd            40 Jun  6 01:21 radvd
drwx--x---.  2 root           root             40 Jun  6 01:21 mdadm
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jun  6 01:21 certmonger
drwx--x--x.  2 setroubleshoot setroubleshoot   40 Jun  6 01:21 setroubleshoot
-rw-r--r--.  1 root           root              4 Jun  6 01:21 auditd.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             60 Jun  6 01:21 dbus
srw-rw-rw-.  1 root           root              0 Jun  6 01:21 rpcbind.sock
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root           lp               80 Jun  6 01:21 cups
drwxr-xr-x.  2 avahi          avahi            80 Jun  6 01:21 avahi-daemon
-rw-------.  1 root           root             11 Jun  6 01:21 alsactl.pid
-rw-r--r--.  1 root           root              4 Jun  6 01:21 chronyd.pid
-rw-r--r--.  1 root           root              4 Jun  6 01:21 ksmtune.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root            100 Jun  6 01:21 abrt
-rw-------.  1 root           root              4 Jun  6 01:21 gssproxy.pid
srw-rw-rw-.  1 root           root              0 Jun  6 01:21 gssproxy.sock
-rw-------.  1 root           root              0 Jun  6 01:21 xtables.lock
drwxr-x---.  2 root           root             40 Jun  6 01:21 firewalld
-rw-r--r--.  1 root           root              4 Jun  6 01:21 dhclient-enp0s3.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             80 Jun  6 01:21 NetworkManager
-rw-------.  1 root           root              5 Jun  6 01:21 sm-notify.pid
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root           root            180 Jun  6 01:21 lock
-rw-------.  1 root           root              5 Jun  6 01:21 syslogd.pid
-rw-r--r--.  1 root           root              5 Jun  6 01:21 sshd.pid
-rw-r--r--.  1 root           root              5 Jun  6 01:21 crond.pid
-rw-r--r--.  1 root           root              5 Jun  6 01:21 atd.pid
-rw-r--r--.  1 root           root              4 Jun  6 01:21 libvirtd.pid
----------.  1 root           root              0 Jun  6 01:21 cron.reboot
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             60 Jun  6 01:21 tuned
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root           root            220 Jun  6 01:21 libvirt
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             40 Jun  6 01:21 plymouth
drwx------.  2 root           root             40 Jun  6 01:22 udisks2
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root           root             80 Jun  6 01:24 console
drwx--x--x.  4 root           gdm             120 Jun  6 01:24 gdm
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root           root             60 Jun  6 01:24 user
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root           utmp           1536 Jun  6 01:24 utmp
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root           root            160 Jun  6 01:24 udev
drwxr-xr-x. 17 root           root            420 Jun  6 01:25 systemd
drwxr-xr-x. 37 root           root           1140 Jun  6 01:25 .
```

`ps -eaf |grep nginx`

```
root       698   685  0 01:21 ?        00:00:00 runsv nginx
root       748   698  0 01:21 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/ngin
root       749   698  0 01:21 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx -p /var/opt/gitlab/nginx
gitlab-+   800   749  0 01:21 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
gitlab-+   801   749  0 01:21 ?        00:00:00 nginx: cache manager process
yen       6683  3840  0 01:44 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

[Output of `ps -eaf |grep nginx` and `netstat -tulpn |grep 80` before and after.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLYhB.png)

Here's the output of `ps -eaf |grep nginx`

```
root       669     1  0 21:50 ?        00:00:00 runsvdir -P /opt/gitlab/service log: svlogd: warning: unable to lock directory: /var/log/gitlab/nginx: temporary failure svlogd: fatal: no functional log directories. svlogd: warning: unable to lock directory: /var/log/gitlab/nginx: temporary failure svlogd: fatal: no functional log directories. svlogd: warning: unable to lock directory: /var/log/gitlab/nginx: temporary failure svlogd: fatal: no functional log directories. .....
root      4333   669  0 21:57 ?        00:00:00 runsv nginx
root      4348  4333  0 21:57 ?        00:00:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/nginx
root      4374  4333  0 21:57 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx -p /var/opt/gitlab/nginx
gitlab-+  4381  4374  0 21:57 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
gitlab-+  4382  4374  0 21:57 ?        00:00:00 nginx: cache manager process
yen      14156  4094  0 23:13 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

Comment: Can you run `ls -lart /var/run/` and paste the output. Nginx is having difficult to read `pid` file which it needs for stop/start/restart and status calls. I suspect there are no enough permissions for it.

Comment: `Jun 05 04:26:05 localhost.localdomain nginx[11491]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)`, I don't see `nginx.pid` in `/var/run/` directory. How are you starting nginx? with sudo privileges?

Comment: Can you ping me the output of `ps -eaf |grep nginx`. I suspect master process of nginx is still running

Comment: I start nginx with the command `sudo systemctl start nginx`.

Comment: Can you run `kill -9 749` followed by `ps -eaf |grep nginx` and `netstat -tulpn |grep 80` and paste the output?

Comment: Screenshot of the output are added.

Comment: okay. You still have worker process, cache manager and other processes, run `kill -9 698`, `kill -9 748`, `kill -9 800`, `kill -9 801` , `kill -9 30841` and `kill -9 30843` then run `ps -eaf |grep nginx` and `netstat -tulpn |grep 80`

Comment: @harshavmb after running `kill -9 -xxxx`, it seems to have error. I had edited the image that i uploaded previously.

Comment: Pastebins are blocked here. Can you paste the output alone? It's very simple kill all the nginx  processes and then start nginx. Should work

Comment: You mean the output of `ps -eaf |grep nginx` and `netstat -tulpn |grep 80`?

Comment: Output of ps -eaf | grep nginx

Comment: Added the output.

Comment: kill all the processes shown in the output and start nginx

Comment: after killing the processes, i still see them running when I run `ps -eaf |grep nginx`. Is it normal?

Comment: Nope, it's not normal. Kill should terminate the processes. Check why the processes aren't killed. Try with `sudo kill`. If you have already tried, start nginx and see if you see the same issue.

Comment: I killed the processes but when i start nginx, still show the same problem.

Comment: Do you have access to reboot the host? If so, reboot and try. Can you try restart nginx with `sudo nginx restart`

Comment: `nginx: invalid option: "restart"`.
i run `sudo nginx` then output shows `nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)`

Comment: okay. nginx is already running on 80 port. You need to kill all of them. Not sure how the processes are starting themselves after killing. It is very weird. Can you consider rebooting the machine, that might kill all the nginx processes

Comment: Same problem after i reboot my machine.

Comment: You should investigate why the processes are running after being killed. Not sure how they are starting themselves

Comment: I will try to investigate. Thanks for your help. :D

Comment: Was this solved? I am facing a similar issue on my server.

Comment: @yenng can you provide the your Nginx Sever configuration file I think if you give it to me i can provide a solution. If your are using linux type these command sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default and give me the outputs of the file.

Answer (score 4):

Check your error log with `sudo cat /var/log/nginx/error.log|less`
You can also with WinScp by entering the path **/var/log/nginx/**

In my case had the syntax error.
In my server configuration file I had: `server_name {api.mydomain.com};`

The correct is: `server_name api.mydomain.com;`